# SMTP Email send with custom Content-Type

Tags: c#, .net

I'm sendig email with .NET SmtpClient with attachment file.
File has extension ".xls" I need it to be send with 
Content-Type: application/excel;
but it's seneded with 
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;

Tried to create attachemtnt with set content type specified  but no effect

Attachment data = new Attachment(fileStream, new ContentType("application/excel; name=asd.xls"));

also in this way:
 Attachment data = new Attachment(fileStream, "file.xls", "application/excel");

Is my code wrong or maybe SMTP server overrides Content-Type somehow??
( I have been tried 3 differnet servers )

```
MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("aaa@interia.pl", "Tom S");
        MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress("bbb@interia.pl", "John B");
        const string fromPassword = "my_pass";
        string body = "new message";

        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "poczta.interia.pl",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
            Timeout = 20000
        })
        {
            using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress))
            {
                message.Subject = Environment.MachineName;
                message.Body = body;

                using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"E:\ExcellOld.xls"))
                {
                    Attachment data = new Attachment(fileStream, new ContentType("application/excel"));
                    message.Attachments.Add(data);
                    smtp.Send(message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: HTTP you cannot send a binary file like excel directly.  If you look at Pedro solution below he is using System.Net.Mime.ContentType which is converting the binary to a Base 64 string.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The correct content-type for excel files is application/vnd.ms-excel, try with this code pls.

```
 MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("aaa@interia.pl", "Tom S");
        MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress("bbb@interia.pl", "John B");
        const string fromPassword = "my_pass";
        string body = "new message";

        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "poczta.interia.pl",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
            Timeout = 20000
        })
        {
            using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress))
            {
                message.Subject = Environment.MachineName;
                message.Body = body;

                using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"E:\ExcellOld.xls"))
                {
                    System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(fileStream, ct);
                    message.Attachments.Add(attach);
                    smtp.Send(message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes i know but I need it to be send with "application/excel" Content-Type for client system recognition

Comment: The best way is to change this value in the client, from application/excel to the new one

Comment: but its impossible client its old app with no chance to be changed :(

any ideas ?

Comment: Remove the  System.Net.Mime.ContentType code and change the attachment code to this   System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(fileStream,"file.xls","application/excel"); Try this pls.

Comment: ites exacaly what I posted as my code example I am using System.Net.Mail.Attachment there

Comment: oh sry, i was testing in my pc. With your initial code and it should work, the MediaType is "application/excel" and the email is sended with the file in correct format.